# How to give multiple if conditions in rails filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to call a rails filter `caches_action` only if it passes two conditions. I have a instance variable set `@page`in application controller which I can access in any controller. Now the filter action I am trying to pass is as follows.

With one `if` condition.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 caches_action :listing,  if: -> { @page.present? }

 def listing

 end
end
```

Now this is working fine. Now I am trying to give multiple conditions using proc as follows. I am not sure about the syntax.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

     caches_action :listing,  if: -> { @page.present? }, 
                  :if => Proc.new{ |controller| 
                        controller.do_something? and 
                        controller.some_other_thing? }


     def listing

     end
end
```

Can somebody please show me the right way to give multiple if conditions ?

Comment: can't you do something like this  `caches_action :listing,  :if => Proc.new{ |controller| @page.present? && controller.do_something? && controller.some_other_thing? }` ?

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: yes sure, let me know , if it works or not .

Comment: why not define all your conditions in a seperate method and then call `if: { my_conditions(@page) }`

Comment: @TinusWagner and remember to name the separate method with a `?` at the end, since it returns a boolean.

Comment: Totally right @RoryO'Kane!